# How to delete dynamic component in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I used Nuxt.js with Vue.js. I added dynamic component like this.

```
// pages/index.vue
<template>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <component v-for="item in buttons" :is="item" :key="item.id" :buttons="buttons" />
    <span class="add-search" @click="add">ADD</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const dynamicComponentFilter = () => import("@/components/ProductFilter");

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttons: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.buttons.push(dynamicComponentFilter);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and in the component

```
// components/productFilter.vue
<template>
..........
  <span class="del" @click="delQuerysToStore(item)">del</span>
..
..
..
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["buttons", "item"],

  methods: {
  delQuerysToStore(item) {
      this.buttons.splice(this.buttons.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

like this.
when I click add button, then appear component per click.
and when I click del button, then delete last component...
I want to delete the component that corresponds to the button I clicked.

Why didn't work indexOf? I watch `console.log(this.buttons.indexOf(item));`, it did work! When I click second button, then appear index 1. But Why didn't work at component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not have access to `this.buttons` in `components/productFilter.vue` because `this.buttons` is scoped to its component instance and it's not a good practice to provide it in props and to expect reactivity in its parent. I would suggest you to pass the index of this dynamic component in it via props `item-id` and then to emit an event in `delQuerysToStore()` and after that to remove the component in the parent `pages/index.vue`. Example:

```
// components/productFilter.vue

 props: {
   itemId: {
     type: Number,
     default: 0
   }
},
 methods: {
  delQuerysToStore(item) {
      this.$emit('delete', this.itemId)
    }
  }
}
```

```
// pages/index.vue

<template>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <component v-for="(item, index) in buttons" :is="item" :key="item.id" :buttons="buttons" @delete="deleteComponent" :item-id="index"/>
    <span class="add-search" @click="add">ADD</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const dynamicComponentFilter = () => import("@/components/ProductFilter");

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttons: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.buttons.push(dynamicComponentFilter);
    },
    deleteComponent(itemId) {
     this.buttons.splice(itemId, 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In general this is the standard and good practice: Data down -> actions up. You provide data down to lower level components, but the lower level components emit events to their parent and thus the communication work between components.

Comment: data down to lower level components! I got it. I didn't know about that so all my application's were like that... Thank you for your teaching!